# how to get device network information? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

the application i'm currently working on is mobile network dependant,
so my question is, is it possible to get the current mobile network which being used on the device (e.g. 3 UK, T-Mobile)?

also, is there anyway of getting the user's mobile number?

thanks for any help (:

Comment: The answers are more or less correct, but you have to consider that a cell phone not necessarily knows its own phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you are looking for is in the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html). Example usage:

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
final String phoneNumber = tm.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 10):

Phone Number:

```
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String phoneNumber = tm.getLine1Number();
```

Network Type:

```
        // Check each connection type
        boolean connectionAvailable = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        /**
         * WIFI
         */

        /** Check the connection **/
        NetworkInfo network = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        // Make sure the network is available
        if(network != null && network.isAvailable() && network.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            connectionAvailable = true;
        }

        /**
         * 2G/3G
         */            
        /** Check the connection **/
        network = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        // Show the right icon
        if(network != null &&
                (network.getSubtype() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS ||
                 network.getSubtype() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE)) {
            // 2G
        }
        else {
            // 3G
        }

        // Make sure the network is available
        if(network.isAvailable() && network.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            connectionAvailable = true;
        }

        /**
         * 4G
         */

        /** Check the connection **/
        network = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX);

        // Make sure the network is available
        if(network != null && network.isAvailable() && network.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            connectionAvailable = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String msisdn = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
    String carrier = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
}
```